# Angular Material Autocomplete value is always empty and onSelection is never fired

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

So, I have a component only for the autocomplete by angular material and a parent component which has a form and uses this autocomplete once.

When I click on a value to choose from the autocomplete, it doesn't get saved anywhere and is empty. Also, I would expect the onSelection event to fire, but it doesnt. I tried several ways to get the current value from the form field, but whatever way I try, its always empty.

Here is the ts file for the autocomplete:

```
interface GroupOption {
  group: string;
  items: OptGroupItem[];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'sh-ui-forms-mat-autocomplete-optgroup-control;',
  templateUrl: './mat-autocomplete-optgroup-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-autocomplete-optgroup-control.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MatAutocompleteOptgroupControlComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class MatAutocompleteOptgroupControlComponent
  implements OnInit, OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor
{
  @Input()
  label = '';

  /** Liste der Roh-Optionen */
  @Input()
  groupOptions: OptGroupItem[] = [];
  /** Observable für die GUI */
  options$?: Observable<GroupOption[]>;
  /** interne Liste der Optionen zum Filtern, Prüfen etc. von Items */
  private options: GroupOption[] = [];
  private emptyOption: OptGroupItem = {
    group: '',
    name: '',
    id: '',
  };

  control = new FormControl('');

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options$ = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.createGroupOptions(value))
    );
  }

  ngOnChanges(c: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.options = this.groupByGroup(this.groupOptions);
  }

  /** Hilfsfunktion zum Umwandeln der Rohoptionen */
  private groupByGroup(options: OptGroupItem[]): GroupOption[] {
    const groups = groupBy(options, 'group');
    return Object.entries(groups).map(([group, items]) => ({
      group,
      items,
    }));
  }

  /** Filtern und erstellen der Optionen für die GUI */
  private createGroupOptions(filter: any): GroupOption[] {
    let options = this.groupOptions;
    if (filter != null) {
      const searchValue = (filter.name || filter).toString().toLowerCase();

      options = this.groupOptions.filter(option =>
        option.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
      );
    }
    const groups = this.groupByGroup(options);
    return groups;
  }

  /** Liefert ein Roh-Item aus der Liste der Optionen.  */
  private getOptionFromId(options: GroupOption[], id: string): OptGroupItem {
    let retVal = this.emptyOption;
    options.forEach(o => {
      const item = o.items.find(i => i.id === id);
      if (item != null) {
        retVal = item;
      }
    });
    return retVal;
  }

  onChange = (_: string) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: string) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // Behandelt eine Control-Wertänderung von "außen".
  writeValue(value: string) {
    let currentValue = this.getOptionFromId(this.options, value);
    if (currentValue === null) {
      currentValue = this.emptyOption;
    }
    this.control.setValue(currentValue);
  }

  //Auswahl im autocomplete
  onDropdownChange(e: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    const selectedValue = e.option.value.id;
    console.log('onDropdownchange! => selectedValue:');
    console.log(selectedValue);
    this.onChange(selectedValue);
  }

  displayName(option: any): string {
    return option ? option.name : '';
  }

  /** Auswahl im Input-Feld */
  onValueChange(event: any): void {
    event?.preventDefault();
    const value = this.control.value;
    if (!value) {
      this.control.setValue(this.emptyOption);
      this.onChange(this.emptyOption.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Thats the html file for the autocomplete:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <ng-container>
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      [formControl]="control"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      (blur)="onValueChange($event)"
      (keyup.enter)="onValueChange($event)"
    />

    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"

      (optionSelected)="OnDropdownChange($event)"
      [displayWith]="displayName"
    >
      <mat-optgroup
        *ngFor="let option of options$ | async"
        [label]="option.group"
      >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of option.items" [value]="item">
          {{ item.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </ng-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

And thats how I call the component from the parent form component:

```
  <sh-ui-forms-mat-autocomplete-optgroup-control
    [label]="'Einsatz'"
    [groupOptions]="openEinsatzListe$ | async"
    formControlName="einsatzId"
  ></sh-ui-forms-mat-autocomplete-optgroup-control>
```

`openEinsatzListe$` is an observable.

[In the picture you can see how the data from the observable/the optionGroups/options for the autocomplete looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTKKg.png)

Question: Why is no value saved when I select a value?

(Btw, there is another bug if you are interested. If you click in the form field, no values are shown. You have to type a space and remove it again to see the values. Maybe you know the solution for that aswell?)

Comment: Turns out, removing `(blur)="onValueChange($event)"` solves the problem. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Your form control implementation is wrong, Please check this manual: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Basic implementation check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdvhyz?file=src/app/app.component.ts